# How can I group two columns in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select remesa_codigo ,remesa_remesabase
from tb_remesa rem
where rem.remesa_codigo in (364476,366728,366617)
        or rem.remesa_remesabase in (364476,366728,366617)
    group by remesa_codigo,remesa_remesabase
    order by remesa_codigo , remesa_remesabase desc
```

[image]

in this way !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYazn.png)

Comment: I assume the colors indicate how you're trying to order these results. That is, order by A but then switch to B if B found in A. Then back to A. This is odd. What do these columns represent, and are there other columns that may help achieve what you need?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, the only compo that has in compu is that remesa_codigo has a column called remesa_isbase of type (true or false) this one is set to true when it is parent

Comment: I thought about doing it with an order by but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: seems like a connect by with Order Siblings clause

Comment: Providing some sample data (including your true/false column) would be very helpful. I almost solved this with multiple ranks prior to knowing about this parent flag.

Comment: see that I put the example in the image of the problem I do not know if you understand it ?

Comment: thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that a recursive CTE will work. The db-fiddle can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tRYXpY37zfxKFEmsid3TAj/0):

```
    with recursive parent as (
     select remesa_codigo as parent_id, 
     remesa_codigo,
     remesa_base, 
     remesa_isbase
     from tb_remesa
     where remesa_isbase = 'TRUE'
     union all
     select p.parent_id, 
     a.remesa_codigo, 
     a.remesa_base, 
     a.remesa_isbase
     from tb_remesa a
     join parent p
       on a.remesa_base = p.remesa_codigo
     )
    select remesa_codigo, 
    remesa_base, 
    remesa_isbase
    from parent
    order by parent_id, remesa_codigo
```